# Jpeg library not found -- configure script run for gdk-pixbuf-2.27.1

Tags: gtk, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

```
checking for jpeg_destroy_decompress in -ljpeg... no
configure: WARNING: *** JPEG loader will not be built (JPEG library not found) ***
configure: error: 
*** Checks for JPEG loader failed. You can build without it by passing
*** --without-libjpeg to configure but some programs using GTK+ may
*** not work properly
```

I am getting above error while configure script is run for gdk-pixbuf-2.27.1.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./configure
```

Jpeg library is installed here :----

```
 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.8.4.0
```

Even i did softlink then also same error:----

```
ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so.8.4.0  /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so.8.4.0
```

I have already installed JPEG library. Please suggest how to resolve it ?

Comment: That softlink is completely the wrong thing to do, cross compiling is complicated, you should read something like http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-cross-compiling.html first

Answer (score 1):

Don't Symlink, you should instead just add the respective libjpeg libraries to your path in .bash_profile or .bashrc. Here is an example of how I did it.

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=/usr/local/include:/opt/libjpeg-turbo/include:$CPATH
```